# How to get data from Tkinter object Entry?

Tags: python, tkinter-entry

```
class App():
     def __init__(self):
         self.root = tkinter.Tk()
         self.root.geometry("400x250")

         txt = Entry(self.root,width=20)
         txt.grid(column=1, row=3)

         btn = Button(self.root, text="Click Me", command= self.clicked)
         btn.grid(column=2, row=0)

         self.root.mainloop()    
     

     def clicked():
        res = txt.get()
        print(res)

app = App()
```

I had an error that txt is not defined. How to fix it? I know that this is because of no definition? But how does it have to be?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in your `__init__` :

```
self.txt = Entry(self.root,width=20)
```

And in your `clicked`:

```
res = self.txt.get()
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```py
import tkinter
class App():
     def __init__(self):
         self.root = tkinter.Tk()
         self.root.geometry("400x250")

         txt = tkinter.Entry(self.root,width=20)
         self.txt=txt
         txt.grid(column=1, row=3)

         btn = tkinter.Button(self.root, text="Click Me", command= self.clicked)
         btn.grid(column=2, row=0)

         self.root.mainloop()    
     

     def clicked(self):
        res = self.txt.get()
        print(res)

app = App()
```

does it work now?